# Wordpress post, styling category list wp_get_object_terms

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On single.php I'm trying to display a list of the current post categories (with child cats), formatted like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="parent_cat_title">Cat 1</li>
<li class="child_cat"><a href="[the link]">Child 1</a></li>
<li class="child_cat"><a href="[the link]">Child 2</a></li>
<li class="child_cat"><a href="[the link]">Child 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li class="parent_cat_title">Cat 2</li>
<li class="child_cat"><a href="[the link]">Child 1</a></li>
<li class="child_cat"><a href="[the link]">Child 2</a></li>
<li class="child_cat"><a href="[the link]">Child 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm almost there, how do I change the PHP to output the list like the one above?

```
<?php 
     
     $taxonomy = 'category';
     
     // Get the term IDs assigned to post.
     $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
     
     // Separator between links.
     $separator = ', ';
     
     if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
     
         $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
     
         $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
             'title_li' => '',
             'style'    => 'none',
             'echo'     => false,
             'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
             'include'  => $term_ids
         ) );
     
         $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );
     
         // Display post categories.
         echo  $terms;
     }
    
     ?>
```

Current output:

```
<a href="https://example.com/topic/">Topic</a>, 
<a href="https://example.com/topic/design/">Design</a>, 
<a href="https://example.com/style/">Style</a>, 
<a href="https://example.com/style/floral/">Floral</a>, 
<a href="https://example.com/color/">Color</a>, 
<a href="https://example.com/color/blue/">Blue</a>, 
<a href="https://example.com/color/green/">Green</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // Get top level categories and list them
    $args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'parent' => 0);
    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

    $args2 = array('orderby' => 'name', 'parent' => $category->cat_ID);
    $subcategories = get_categories( $args2 );

    echo '<ul>';
    //Display parent category title
    echo '<li class="parent_cat_title">'. $category->cat_name . '</li>';

    // Display post child categories.
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        echo '<li class="child_cat"><a href="'. get_category_link($subcategory->cat_ID).'">' . $subcategory->cat_name . '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';

    }
?>
```